# Azure AD token subject type (user or app-only?)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to tell whether the incoming token has been issued for a user or application principal just from the token? The only difference I could find was looking for `upn` and `mail` claims (because of B2B users) and then if those are missing marking the token as application only. Is there any better way to tell just from the token?

Comment: So are you looking for a claim that more specifically identifies it as an app-only token?

Comment: Yeah. Exactly what I need. I am aware of being able to call the Graph and pulling the info about the principal, but would like to do it without additional HTTP call.

Comment: Personally I would probably use the way you are doing it now :) Those would never be part of an app-only token. Some other claims which do not exist in app-only tokens are *acr* and *amr*, which are details on how a user was authenticated.

Comment: If the token is being issued to call a resource (aka an access token) I believe app authentication will have `roles` and user authentication will use `scopes`.

Comment: That makes sense, but in my scenario, there are no scopes or roles used. The token is used for authentication, authorization is done on the application side based on RBAC built-in. That’s why I need a way to tell which token is which, because there are different permission levels available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no claim currently which will tell you this explicitly. However, presence of `acr` and `amr` (which describe how the user authenticated) would be a very strong indication that there is a user involved.